# Decode in JavaScript encoded Base64 value in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, base64

I'm trying to decrypt "window.btoa" in PHP, please see my PHP code in below.

```
<script>
var url = "?url=";
var input = 'some text';
var encrypt = window.btoa( input );
var link = "www.domain.com/"+url+encrypt;
</script>
```

My Link generated as below
www.domain.com/?url=c29tZSB0ZXh0

PHP code in below

```
<?php
$testURL = $_GET['url'];
echo $testURL;
?>
```

Please guide me how to decrypt this value.

Comment: you have a syntax error `$_GET['url]` and if what you posted is the actual code, it's a typo. Edit: This as per your original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49599140/1 of course.

Comment: you still haven't added the error(s) you got. Thus making this unclear

Comment: `btoa` is not encryption, it is encoding, it is Base64 encoding badly named: Base64 uses the "A-Z", "a-z", "0-9", "+", "/" and "=" characters to encode the string.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Edited, thanks

Comment: And it's clearly defined ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa), [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-btoa)). So...do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Don't understand the downvoting and arrogance of some comments. It's quite a simple and clear question which could be answered short and precisely as done by Lece. Either question and answer fitted perfectly my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javascript `btoa` function will encode your string to base-64. To decode the result in PHP use the `base64_decode` function;

```
 <?php
     echo base64_decode('c29tZSB0ZXh0');
 ?>
```

Will print;

> some text

Answer (score 0):

`btoa` is not encryption, it is encoding, it is Base64 encoding badly named: Base64 uses the "A-Z", "a-z", "0-9", "+", "/" and "=" characters to encode the string.

See [Window btoa() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp), first hit on Google for "window.btoa".

Using [Base64 -> hexadecimal string decoder](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php?lang=en) `c29tZSB0ZXh0` is decoded to hex: `736F6D652074657874` and text: `some text`.